# How add state dir to embedded Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using embedded Kafka for junit and I want to set state dir for embedded Kafka.

I have tried to set streams config but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The client has no idea that it's talking to an embedded Vs. a real broker - they are the same. The state.dir is a client-side concept only.

If setting the `StreamsConfig` is "not working" you must have made a mistake.

Edit your question to show your code and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change where the broker is writing it's data, you need to pass in the corresponding configs via the `Properties`:

```
public EmbeddedKafkaCluster(final int numBrokers,
                            final Properties brokerConfig);
```

I guess you want to set `log.dirs`? Cf. available broker config: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs